# Inner join and possibly a cte? Inner join and partial match in same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently match `#teacher` to `#coursesCSV` using `TeacherId`, So with the `INNER JOIN` there's a one-one and I get one row. Once I get this match, I need to display the possible `#coursesCsv.IsExpired` for that particular `TeacherId` in that same row. So I match the first 3 chars and the last 4 chars, but ignore the 3 chars in the middle. With this criteria, there would only be two matches, and that's why the result displays 'OK/NOK'. The maximum number of matches here will be 2.

So the result should look like the following:

```
teacherid       isexpired   WhatMatched
ABC-001-1225    OK          OK/NOK
```

If that's too difficult, another possible result would be a count:

```
teacherid       isexpired   WhatMatched
ABC-001-1225    OK          2
```

I've been trying get a '2' for `WhatMatched` but I keep getting 3. And I'mt stuck there. The important thing is that the result can only consist of 1 row.

The reason I'm doing this is that we have a grid that populates using `#teacher.TeacherId` `inner join` `#coursesCSV`, and this row is evaluated and approved by a user. In this case, he will naturally see 1 row: **ABC-001-1225** and **OK**. The website will not let him approve because there's a **NOK** (ABC-002-1225). I'm adding this so that he knows he needs to check something instead of having to ask me why he can't approve since it says **OK**.

This is the query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#teacher') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #teacher
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#coursesCsv') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #coursesCsv

create table #teacher
(
    TeacherID varchar(20),
    FullName varchar(30),
    DeptId int
)

insert into #teacher select 'ABC-001-1225', 'Roy Brown', 3


create table #coursesCsv
(
    IsExpired varchar(3),
    TeacherID varchar(20),
    DeptId int
)
insert into #coursesCsv select 'OK', 'ABC-001-1225', 3
insert into #coursesCsv select 'NOK', 'ABC-002-1225', 3
insert into #coursesCsv select 'OK', 'XYZ-002-1225', 3

select t.teacherid, c.isexpired, c.coursecnt, c.prefix
from #teacher t 
inner join 
 (
   select 
      teacherid,
      left(teacherid, 3) as 'Prefix',
      isexpired,
      count(*)
      over (partition by right(teacherid,4)) as coursecnt
   from #coursesCsv
 ) as c
on t.teacherid = c.teacherid
and left(t.teacherid, 3) = left(c.teacherid, 3)
```

Comment: Seems to me that this count `count(*)
      over (partition by right(teacherid,4))` will yield 3 in your example.  You're asking it to count all the instances where the last 4 digits = 1225 there.  Since there are three like that, you're going to get three.  Maybe you should add the Prefix to your partition so that it only counts 2 for ABC-1225.

Comment: I mentioned in the post that I would like to match the first 3 chars and the last 4 chars, but ignore the 3 chars in the middle.

Comment: Yes, @amcdermott demonstrates what I mean in the answer below.  The partition is too broad and needs to be constrained further by the Prefix.

Answer (score 2):

I may not understand this 100% .... but I think you need to partition by the first 3 and last 4 characters of `teacherid`. So...

```
select t.teacherid, c.isexpired, c.coursecnt, c.prefix
from #teacher t 
inner join 
 (
   select 
      teacherid,
      left(teacherid, 3) as 'Prefix',
      isexpired,
      count(*)
      over (partition by left(teacherid, 3), right(teacherid,4)) as coursecnt
   from #coursesCsv
 ) as c
on t.teacherid = c.teacherid
and left(t.teacherid, 3) = left(c.teacherid, 3)
```

Comment: This result is displayed in a grid for a user to approve, but only the INNER JOIN will be displayed. In this case, the inner join returns 1 row and IsExpired is 'OK'. But there's another match (using the first 3 and last 4 chars) that is 'NOK'. The site wil not let him approve, so by showing the count, he will know that he needs to check another record.

Comment: Similar to your OP, I'm not sure I fully understand your comment either - does my suggestion give you something unexpected or is it incomplete.

Comment: This is exactly what I noted in my comment to the OP above.  The partition needed to to include the Prefix.